# right join in my sql and subquery

Tags: mysql

In this query I am trying to get email address of users that were "created" in month of June 2016 and have never existed before but this does not seem to work at all.

I need to  filter out users emails that have existed before June 2016 and get only the new ones created in June 2016.

What seems wrong with this query?

```
select DISTINCT SF.customer_email, SF.created_at,  historcialEmails.customeremail,
historcialEmails.createdAt 
FROM 
sales_flat_order SF
RIGHT JOIN
(
select SFO.customer_email
AS customeremail,
SFO.created_at as createdAt
FROM 
sales_flat_order SFO 
WHERE
DATE(SFO.created_at) <= '2016-05-31'
) AS historcialEmails
ON historcialEmails.customeremail = SF.customer_email
WHERE
YEAR(DATE(SF.created_at)) = '2016'
AND 
MONTH(DATE(SF.created_at)) = '6'
AND 
SF.customer_email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long and format dependent for comment but, incidentally, appropriately indexed, the following is optimised:

```
sf.created_at <= '2016-05-31 00:00:00'
...
AND sf.created_at BETWEEN '2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-01 00:00:00'
WHERE sf.customer_email IS NULL
```

To get back to the answer, you will notice that I've swapped the position of the WHERE clause. Except for IS NULL, conditions on OUTER JOINED tables (sf is the outer joined table in your example) belong on the JOIN itself. Note also that use of RIGHT JOIN is vanishingly rare. Normally a LEFT JOIN would be used, and the tables swapped around.

Comment: Thank you but mind pointing out what is actually wrong with my version of the query? I am curious to know where the error is.

Comment: Joining positions switched ,alright. (but that wouldn't logically make a difference here, No?), adding time stamp to date, okay but why sf.created_at BETWEEN '2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-07-01 00:00:00' should make any difference ? I am still not sure why this should work and not the other one.Also, I did use your version of the query. Same results as before . @strawberry

Comment: done, I was using the wrong JOIN. Needed LEFT join instead